# JQuery - removing entry from a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a cookie which I would like to read then remove one entry from it based in the widget ID.

```
if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
            $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                /* STOP event bubbling */
                e.stopPropagation();    
            }).click(function () {
                if(confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/controllers/widget.php",
            data: {
                method: "remove",
                widgetID:thisWidget.id,
                   },
                   dataType: "json",

                });

        var mycookie = $.cookie("mypreferences");
```

//remove based on id here

---

as suggested...

var cookieName = 'myCookie';
                            var cookie = $.cookie("preferences");

```
                        var cookie = cookie.split('|');

                         $(cookie).each(function(index){

                               var thisCookieData = this.split(',');


                            alert(thisCookieData);


                              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `split()` to get individual elements from your cookie and than loop through them, and remove it. and then combine the rest of your entries and save it.

split reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp